# Changing colour of floating action button

Tags: flutter

I would like to change the colour of my floating action button, as it is currently set to the standard blue, but the below does not seem to be working.

Probably an easy fix that I am overlooking. Any thoughts?

```
floatingActionButton: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 80, height: 80),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong, size: 39),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CameraScreen()));
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            colors.Color(0xffC6CBD1),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `primary` attribute in your style, like this:

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  primary: colors.Color(0xffC6CBD1)
),
```